# NodeJS + EJS + Promise : page is not displayed until the promise is fulfilled

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise, ejs

I retrieve data from a web service in a promise and display it using EJS. The problem is that the HTTP page is not displayed until the promise is fulfilled which makes sense since I call render inside "then".

Is there a way to have the HTTP page displayed without "data" and the "data" displayed when the webService call completes?

```
var webService = new webService();
webService.GetData("https://somewebservice.com")
    .then( (result) =>
    {
        let options: Object = 
        {
            "data": result
        };

        this.render(req, res, "index", options);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

So this might mean you have to restructure your code.  But there is something called an observable.  It's like a promise, but you subscribe to it which means that after you make the call the callback function is always monitoring it and updating whenever something is returned.  It would require a restructure but here is a link to a tutorial.

It would also be good to note that your code will probably need to be restructured anyway, the page will need to load and then make a call for the data if that's the way you want to handle it.

Let me know if this helps.

https://medium.com/@benlesh/learning-observable-by-building-observable-d5da57405d87

Comment: I tried to modify the code to have the page making the call but probably I don't know how to do that correctly. In the HTTP page i see _[object Promise]_ instead of the actual result. Here you have the code:   

`private render(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction)  
{  
 let options: Object = 
 {
  "promiseCall": this.callPromise,
 };
 this.render(req, res, "pages/about", options);
}

<div>Promise call result: <%- promiseCall().then((result) => 
{
   console.log("Result from page: " + result);
   return result;
}) %></div>`

Promise call result: [object Promise]

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ended up with is:

1. The page has an onLoad handler on `<body>` that calls a JSON API on my server using '$.getJSON'
2. The JSON API calls the web service using promises and in the last 'then' sets 'res.json'
3. The onLoad handler upon API response updates the HTTP element by setting its text.

This way the page is loaded and displayed then the onLoad handler fires up and deals with the web service and updates the page.

However I would have liked all of this to be transparent, it would have been great if EJS could take care of all of that through a simple assignment.